# canvas createRadialGradient() not working in htc,nexus7 android devices

Tags: android, canvas, radial-gradients

Im using canvas methods(circles) into my application.The gradient color code is not working in the HTC One S,Nexus 7 Devices.It comes with a white background colors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!